# Difference between Activity Context and BroadcastReceiver Context

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to get all BTS tower with following piece of code in OnRecieve() of BroadcastReceiver

```
TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

List<NeighboringCellInfo> BTSList = telManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();

for (int i = 0; i < BTSList.size(); i++) { 
   int cid = BTSList.get(i).getCid();
}
```

if I use this code in an Activity, it works well. but using this in BroadcastReceiver return nothing.

I think my main problem is with Context, but I'm not sure.

Comment: have you verified that the BroadcastReciever was called? How do you define "in BroadcastReciever return nothing"? if your BroadcastReciever is triggered outside the android-gui-thread and you update the gui from the bc-receiver you may need to sync via a `Handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes 
The problem is related to the context, but not because of its type, because the context is involved with receiving sms. 
To solve this problem, you must create a thread and get bts info in it.
it is better that your thread to be call with 20 seconds delay . you can use this in OnRecieve()

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
                       // get info here 

      }
 }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind when with this because the Context should not matter. First, I assume you added the ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES to the manifest of the Application with the BroadcastReceiver?

Second, did you by chance try getAllCellInfo? I only ask because of the documentation for getNeighboringCellInfo which said it would be deprecated in the future:

Returns the neighboring cell information of the device. The getAllCellInfo is preferred and use this only if getAllCellInfo return nulls or an empty list.

In the future this call will be deprecated.

Returns
List of NeighboringCellInfo or null if info unavailable.
Requires Permission: (@link android.Manifest.permission#ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES}